# Is there a way to flip back and forth between two options?

Tags: shortcut

I am using the Transform pivot point, one time around the cursor, and the other time around the individual origin. Is there a way to flip between them without the need to go to the menu and flip them manually every time. That'd safe a ton of time and effort.

Comment: You could write a Python operator and assign it to a shortcut, but the built-in operator selects from a list and doesn't have a toggle.

Comment: @MartyFouts that would take even more time I guess

Comment: I guess the quickest method is to hit the period key on the main keyboard and swipe the mouse down or right on the pie menu to flip between the two. Certainly faster than going up to the top menu bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import bpy


def main1(context):
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'INDIVIDUAL_ORIGINS'


def main2(context):
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'CURSOR'

class IndividualOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.individual"
    bl_label = "individual"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main1(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class CursorOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.cursor"
    bl_label = "cursor"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main2(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(IndividualOperator.bl_idname, text=IndividualOperator.bl_label)
    self.layout.operator(CursorOperator.bl_idname, text=CursorOperator.bl_label)


# Register and add to the "object" menu (required to also use F3 search "Simple Object Operator" for quick access).
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(IndividualOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CursorOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(IndividualOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CursorOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

1. run the script
2. in viewport press F3 -> search for "cursor"

[image]

right click, then either assign shortcut or to quick favorite

3. do the same as in 2) just with "individual"

now you can change it with one keystroke of your choice.

i put as a test on ctrl-shift 1 and 2, result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Edit -> Preferences -> Keymap
2. In keymaps expand 3D View -> 3D View (Global) and press Add new at the bottom of this section.
3. None key building will be added. Expand it, replace none text field by `wm.context_toggle_enum`
4. 3 additional fields will appear. Add these values:

| Field | Value |
| --- | --- |
| context | scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point |
| Value | CURSOR |
| Value | INDIVIDUAL_ORIGINS |

[Value reference](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.ToolSettings.html#bpy.types.ToolSettings.transform_pivot_point)

Instead of `A` input a hotkey that you want. In my case is `F5`:

[image]

PS. BTW John Eason's comment is right. Why don't you use pie menu for that? It is a quick method to change pivot point, that's provided by default. It is as quickly as pressing the button:

[image]

To do that, press <kbd>.</kbd> (dot) then move cursor slightly to the left (3D cursor) or bottom (individual origins) while holding <kbd>.</kbd> button.